# Impressionist gem and Friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with impressionist and friendly id, I want to show page views in my articles. The problem is that impressionist is not registering the number of views.

It's the same problem [here on impressionist's bug tracker](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/22).

My articles model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_impressionable
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
```

Articles controller:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if request.path != article_path(@article)
    redirect_to @article, status: :moved_permanently
  end
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html 
     format.json { render json: @article }
  end    
end
```

I also restarted the server, but having the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok there is a work around. Just add impressionist(@model) in the show controller

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  impressionist(@article)

   if request.path != article_path(@article)
      redirect_to @article, status: :moved_permanently
   end
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @article }
  end    
end
```

Comment: Note to also remove the impressionist call from the controller as detailed in step 4 in the wiki: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#usage.

Answer (score 1):

Little tip for unique functionality:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  impressionist(@article, nil, { unique: [:session_hash] })
end
```